# How to access Django Model-Fields inside a Django-View?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So, what is the best way for me to access my model-field-data inside my get_context_data method?

```
    class PersonView(TemplateView):

         def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
```

For one, I'm importing my models in like so (works fine):

```
  from person.models import People
```

And I want to compare to model fields in particular (works fine):

```
   create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
   last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

I'm looking to do something like this in my view, and then send the "pass" data to my context, so I can use it in my template ( context['date_set'] = date_set )

```
    if create_date === last_update:
       date_set = False
    else:
       date_set = True
```

I've tried various things, for example:

```
  last_update = people.get(last_update='last_update')
```

but it times out on me, so I can't even check the logger info data.

My "people" data above is built here:

```
      for people in peoples:
        people, created = People.objects.update_or_create(
            id=people.student_id
        )
```

Comment: What is `attendance`?..

Comment: `pass = something` should raise a `SyntaxError` as `pass` is a keyword.

Comment: hey @Sayse - i updated my code above. I build "people" using the update_or_create API. -DeepSpace - thanks, switching pass to something else

Comment: @michaelsebastian:  please just paste the entire view code and not just snippets.  I still can’t understand if you want to figure out `date_set` in memory or in the query.

Comment: @2ps ok sorry about that, wasn't sure if that would overwhelm with so much code...I'll try to get it up soon